# Minecraft Fabric API import errors

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I have errors with my imports and other things, and all errors is "package does not exist" and "cannot find symbol". I'm using minecraft version 1.20.4

there is error:
Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\mightywinter\src\main\java\com\mightywinter\screen\myScreen.java:3: error: package com.mojang.blaze3d.systems does not exist
import com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem;
^
C:\mightywinter\src\main\java\com\mightywinter\screen\myScreen.java:4: error: package net.minecraft.client.gui does not exist
import net.minecraft.client.gui.DrawContext;
^
C:\mightywinter\src\main\java\com\mightywinter\screen\myScreen.java:5: error: package net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.ingame does not exist
import net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.ingame.HandledScreen;
^
C:\mightywinter\src\main\java\com\mightywinter\screen\myScreen.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import net.minecraft.client.render.GameRenderer;
^
symbol:   class GameRenderer
location: package net.minecraft.client.render
C:\mightywinter\src\main\java\com\mightywinter\screen\myScreen.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class myScreen extends HandledScreen {
^
symbol: class HandledScreen
C:\mightywinter\src\main\java\com\mightywinter\screen\myScreen.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
protected void drawBackground(DrawContext context, float delta, int mouseX, int mouseY) {
^
symbol:   class DrawContext
location: class myScreen
C:\nig\mightywinter\src\main\java\com\mightywinter\screen\myScreen.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
private void renderProgressArrow(DrawContext context, int x, int y) {
^
symbol:   class DrawContext
location: class myScreen
C:\mightywinter\src\main\java\com\mightywinter\screen\myScreen.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
public void render(DrawContext context, int mouseX, int mouseY, float delta) {
^
symbol:   class DrawContext
location: class myScreen
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

So, there is my code:

```
package com.mightywinter.screen;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.DrawContext;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.ingame.HandledScreen;
import net.minecraft.client.render.GameRenderer;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerInventory;
import net.minecraft.text.Text;
import net.minecraft.util.Identifier;

public class MyScreen extends HandledScreen<MyScreenHandler> {
    private static final Identifier TEXTURE = new Identifier("mightywinter", "textures/gui/gem_polishing_station_gui.png");

    public MyScreen(MyScreenHandler handler, PlayerInventory inventory, Text title) {
        super(handler, inventory, title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();
        titleY = 1000;
        playerInventoryTitleY = 1000;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawBackground(DrawContext context, float delta, int mouseX, int mouseY) {
        RenderSystem.setShader(GameRenderer::getPositionTexProgram);
        RenderSystem.setShaderColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        RenderSystem.setShaderTexture(0, TEXTURE);
        int x = (width - backgroundWidth) / 2;
        int y = (height - backgroundHeight) / 2;

        context.drawTexture(TEXTURE, x, y, 0, 0, backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight);

        renderProgressArrow(context, x, y);
    }

    private void renderProgressArrow(DrawContext context, int x, int y) {
        if(handler.isCrafting()) {
            context.drawTexture(TEXTURE, x + 85, y + 30, 176, 0, 8, handler.getScaledProgress());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(DrawContext context, int mouseX, int mouseY, float delta) {
        renderBackground(context, mouseX, mouseY, delta);
        super.render(context, mouseX, mouseY, delta);
        drawMouseoverTooltip(context, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```

I tried reintsall java and recreate files